# Determine the time complexity using master theorem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, master-theorem

How would I determine the time complexity using the Master Theorem for the given problem?

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + O(n^d)
```

```
T(n) = 4 T(n/2) + n*log(n)
a = 4, b = 2, d = 1
```

```
1. O(n^d)       if d > logb(a)
2. O(n^d logn)  if d = logb(a) 
3. O(n^logb(a)) if d < logb(a)
```

In my case:

```
log2(4) = 2  --> d < log2(4)
```

```
T(n) = O(n^logb(a)) 
     = O(n^2)
```

Is this correct?

**edit:**

I have made an different approach now, resulting in the same as before though, and following my professors instruction.

```
T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n)

T(n) = 4 T(n/2) + n*log(n) 

         1. Ө(n^(logba))       , if --> f(n) є O(n^(logba-ε)),
T(n) = { 2. Ө(n^(logba) log2n) , if --> f(n) є Ө(n^(logba))
         3. Ө(f(n))            , if --> f(n) є Ω(n^(logba+ε))
```

First I look at the 2nd case

```
f(n)  = n*log(n)
logb^a = log2^4 = 2
n^log24 = n^2
```

The second case does **not** apply because:

```
n*log(n) ∉ Θ(n^logba) —> the runtime of f(n) is smaller, because n*log(n) < n^2
```

Look at the first case if the runtime of f(n) is smaller than n^2

```
1. Ө(n^(logba)) , if --> f(n) є O(n^(logba-ε))

O(n^(logba-ε)) = O(n^(log24-ε))= O(n^2-ε)
n*log(n) ∈ O(n^(log24-ε)) --> works
```

f(n) has O(n^2-ε) as upper limit for worst case scenario,

1. case of Master—Theorems applies:

```
T(n) = Θ(n^log24) = Θ(n^2)
T(n) = Θ(n^2)
```

Comment: It's not clear where you're stuck. Do you know what the master theorem is? Which of the options it provides is applicable here? What did you mean by "for n = 1 -> O(1)"?

Comment: Why don't you put your working in the question in a form that people can understand, and state which piece you have to guess at and why you aren't sure?

Comment: @PaulHankin Hello Paul, thank you for your advice. I updated my question and added my "calculations". What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the master theorem that you've stated here specifically assumes that the additive term has the form O(n<sup>d</sup>). In this case, the additive term is of the form n log n, which is not O(n<sup>1</sup>). This means that you cannot apply the master theorem as you have above.

A useful technique when working with recurrences like these is to sandwich the recurrence between two others. Notice, for example, that T(n) is bounded by these recurrences:

> S(n) = 4S(n / 2) + n
>
> R(n) = 4T(n / 2) + n<sup>1+ε</sup>, where ε is some small positive number.

Try solving each of these recurrences using the master theorem and see what you get, keeping in mind that your recurrence solves to a value sandwiched between them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my question and added a new solution - I hope this works !